# Type '[NSObject : AnyObject]!' does not conform to protocol 'DictionaryLiteralConvertible'

Tags: ios, swift

```
self.textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
                                    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle]
```

This gives a compiler error saying `Type '[NSObject : AnyObject]!' does not conform to protocol 'DictionaryLiteralConvertible'`. I've just started Swift and cannot figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that `NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle` is a Swift enum value and it doesn't conform to the `AnyObject` protocol.  To get around this, call `toRaw()` to convert it to an `Int`:

```
self.textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
                                    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.toRaw()]
```

**Update (for Xcode 6.1):**

The function `toRaw()` has been replaced with the property `rawValue` in Xcode 6.1.

```
self.textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor(),
                                    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.StyleSingle.rawValue]
```

Comment: Thank you. Weird that enums don't conform to `AnyObject`, though.

Comment: I believe enums don't conform because they are a Swift-only feature.  The code you are writing needs to be compatible with Objective-C since that is what the Cocoa framework is written in.

Comment: To tell the truth, type `Int` doesn't conform to the `AnyObject` protocol either.  But if you have `Foundation` imported, then the `Int` gets converted to an `NSNumber` for you.